# How do I write a complex type safe composer function in typescript, and returns a Component with composed props and a hook

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have some simple logic here, however i can't wrap my head around typescript.

I have the following interfaces

```
interface Data<RecordType extends {}> {
  records: RecordType[];
}

enum DefaultActions {
  READ = "READ",
  WRITE = "WRITE",
}

type DefaultActionType =
  | {
      type: DefaultActions.READ;
    }
  | {
      type: DefaultActions.WRITE;
      payload: Record<string, any>;
    };

interface DataSourceObject<
  RecordType extends {},
  ActionType extends DefaultActionType,
  ReturnType,
  StateType extends Data<RecordType>,
  PropsType
> {
  props: PropsType;
  reducer?: (state: StateType, action: ActionType) => StateType;
  actionCreator: ActionCreatorType<
    RecordType,
    ActionType,
    ReturnType,
    StateType,
    PropsType
  >;
}

type ActionCreatorType<
  RecordType extends {},
  ActionType extends DefaultActionType,
  ReturnType,
  StateType extends Data<RecordType>,
  PropsType
> = (
  props: PropsType,
  state: StateType,
  dispatch: (action: ActionType) => void
) => ReturnType;

type FooActions = { type: "SET_FOOLISH"; payload: { isFoolish: true } };

type FooProps = {
  isFoo: boolean;
  foo: boolean;
  fooTable: string[];
  food: string;
  fooLish: boolean;
};

type FooReturns = {
  isFoo: boolean,
  hasFood: boolean,
  setFoolish: (isFoolish: boolean) => void;
};

const foo = {
  props: {
    isFoo: true,
    foo: true,
    fooTable: [],
    food: "string",
    fooLish: false,
  } as FooProps,
  reducer: <RecordType extends {}>(
    state: FooProps & Data<RecordType>,
    action: FooActions
  ) => {
    // DO SOME JAVASCRIPT MAGIC...
    return state;
  },
  actionCreator: <RecordType extends {},>(
    props: FooProps,
    state: FooProps & Data<RecordType>,
    dispatch
  ) => {
    return {
      isFoo: props.isFoo,

      hasFood: false,
      setFoolish: (isFoolish) => {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_FOOLISH", payload: { isFoolish } });
      },
    } as FooReturns;
  },
};


type BarProps = {
  isBar: boolean;
  barTable: number[];
  barPress: number;
  barTender: string;
  barStool: boolean;
};

type BarReturns = {
  isBar: boolean;
  setBarPress: (isBar: boolean) => void;
  getBarTender: (barTender: string) => void;
  setBarStool: (barStool: boolean) => void;
};


const bar = {
  props: {
    isBar: true,
    barTable: [],
    barPress: 10,
    barTender: "",
    barStool: false,
  } as BarProps,
  actionCreator: <RecordType extends {}>(
    props: BarProps,
    state: BarProps & Data<RecordType>,
    dispatch
  ) => {
    return {
      isBar: props.isBar,
      setBarPress(isBar) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_FOOLISH", payload: { isBar } });
      },
      getBarTender(barTender) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_BAR_TENDER", payload: { barTender } });
      },
      setBarStool(barStool) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_BAR_STOOL", payload: { barStool } });
      },
    } as BarReturns;
  },
};
```

As you can see, the interfaces for props, reducers and actionCreators are all different.

I have a composer function that takes an array of DataSources and returns a Component and a hook.

```
const createDataSource = <
  RecordType extends {},
  DS extends DataSourceObject<RecordType, {}, {}, {}, {}>
>(
  dataSources: DS[]
) => {
  return {

    // expect props to be BarProps && FooProps
    Component: (props) => null,
    Hook: () => {},
  };
};
```

And here's how I want to use it.

```
const {Component} = createDataSource([foo, bar]);

const App = () => {
  return <Component isBar isFoo isFoolish />
}
```

Now, coming to the question;
How do I create my types/interfaces such that

1. The props for the component is an intersection of PropTypes.
2. The return value of the Hook is an intersection of the ReturnTypes.
3. How do I make all of this a proper generic such that I can declare foo to be of a particular type, and createDataSource accepts it in the array.

The problem I face at the moment is.

While the code works like a charm, type-safety is entirely broken.

I want this to be a part of a project I would like to open source, but once it is ready.

Any help with advanced typescript would be really welcome

I have tried looking at inferring the type of props, and extracting the argument types etc.

I keep getting stuck with Generics.